# Unable to reconnect after cancelling BLE peripheral connection iOS

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

In my project I was successful to connect to a Bluetooth LE peripheral and read `CBCharacteristic` value from that device. I am facing an issue. I need to disconnect the peripheral and reconnect the device again if user wishes.

I am using the following steps.

**1. For Disconnecting**:
I am calling
`centralManager?.cancelPeripheralConnection(peripheral)`. This call is completed successfully calling delegate `func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager, didDisconnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, error: NSError?)`

**2. To Reconnect**: I start scanning for peripherals, as I did when the app launched `centralManager!.scanForPeripheralsWithServices(nil, options: nil)`

But this call never calls the delegate     `func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager, didDiscoverPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : AnyObject], RSSI: NSNumber)` where I try to connect the BLE discovered peripheral.

My question is what is the best practice to disconnect a BLE peripheral and reconnect it again in iOS. Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thats not the right way to re-connect to BLE.

Per [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/BestPracticesForInteractingWithARemotePeripheralDevice/BestPracticesForInteractingWithARemotePeripheralDevice.html):

**Reconnecting to Peripherals**

> Using the Core Bluetooth framework, there are three ways you can
>   reconnect to a peripheral. You can:
>
> 1. Retrieve a list of known peripherals—peripherals that you’ve    discovered or connected to in the past—using the
>      `retrievePeripheralsWithIdentifiers:` method. If the peripheral you’re
>      looking for is in the list, try to connect to it. This reconnection
>      option is described in Retrieving a List of Known Peripherals.
> 2. Retrieve a list of peripheral devices that are currently connected to    the system using the `retrieveConnectedPeripheralsWithServices:`
>      method. If the peripheral you’re looking for is in the list, connect
>      it locally to your app. This reconnection option is described in
>      Retrieving a List of Connected Peripherals.
> 3. Scan for and discover a peripheral using the
>      `scanForPeripheralsWithServices:options:` method. If you find it,
>      connect to it. These steps are described in Discovering Peripheral
>      Devices That Are Advertising and Connecting to a Peripheral Device
>      After You’ve Discovered It.

Comment: Thanks @Abhinav for your answer. I am checking all the 3 possible ways for reconnection. Did I use proper call for disconnection from BLE device?

Comment: Yes disconnection is all good. The link I shared is Best Practices for dealing with BLE devices. Very informative. I would advise you to go through once... would definitely add in your knowledge base. Could you please accept this answer for the benefit of others.

Comment: Let me check them all please . 'retrievePeripheralsWithIdentifiers:' did not help me. I was earlier calling option 3 scanForPeripheralsWithServices:options:. Currently checking option 2.